# Confusion in the definition of an $(n,M,d)$-code $C$

Tags: terminology, definition, coding-theory

I am studying the Main Coding Theory Problem.

In the definition, in Hill's book, an $(n,M,d)$-code $C$ is a code of length $n$, containing $M$ codewords and having minimum distance $d$. However, in the proofs of some results like $A_q(n,1)=q^n$, it seems that he uses that $d$ has minimum distance **at least** $d$.

Later, I found on some online notes the definition where q-ary $(n, M, d)$-code means a code of length $n$ containing exactly $M$ words and with **minimum distance at least $d$.**

Is there a kind of implication? For example "*at least* $d$ implies *exactly* $d$"?  Or can we claim this without loss of generality? Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my minimal experience with coding theory, I never encountered that the $d$ in $(n,M,d)$-code actually refers to $d$ being minimal distance at least $d$.

The implication you are asking for is non-existent. At least $d$ will definitely not imply $d$.

I will give you a proof of $A_q(n,1) = q^n$ where $d$ is the exact minimum.

Recall that $A_q(n,1):= \max \{M \in \mathbb{N}_0: \exists [n,M,1]_q-code\}$.

Denote your alphabet with $A$ (where $|A| = q$). Then any $[n,M',1]$-code lives by definition in $A^n$ and thus $A_q(n,1) \leq q^n$. But $C:=A^n$ itself is a $[n,q^n, 1]$-code, so we get $q^n \leq A_q(n,1)$. This shows that

$$A_q(n,1) = q^n$$

Never did I use a weird interpretation of minimal distance "at least $d$".