# An $(n,M,d)$-code $C$ is an $(n,M,d-1)$-code

Tags: definition, cryptography, coding-theory

Let $C$ be an $(n,M,d)$-code, where $n$ is its length, $M$ is its size and $d$ is its minimum distance.

***My question is: Is an $(n,M,d)$-code $C$ also an $(n,M,d-1)$-code? ***

It seems that this doesn't hold. For example let $A:=\Bbb Z_2$ and consider the code
$$C:=\{e_1:=(0,0,0),e_2:=(0,1,1),e_3:=(1,1,0)\}\subseteq A^3.$$
Then, $d(e_1,e_2)=2,d(e_1,e_3)=2,d(e_2,e_3)=2$. So, $d(C)=2$. Therefore, $C$ is a binary  $(3,3,2)$-code.

So $C$ can't be an $(3,3,1)$-code, since there are not codewords in $C$ that differ in 1 digit.

*Could you please give me help?*

Comment: Where did you see the claim that an $(n,M,d)$ is an $(n,M,d-1)$ code?

Comment: You are right, thank you. Let me put it in a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you think this is true?

By definition, the minimal distance of your code is $d$. Thus the same code will never have minimal distance $d-1$.

Literally every code gives you a counterexample!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I was thinking about that because I found the $(n, M, d) $-code defined differently, where $d(C) \geq d$. Check https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3608859/326865

And unfortunately this definition causes extra problems, like this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3610047/on-the-reduction-lemma-the-xistence-of-an-n-1-m-d-1-code

Comment: I see, but even with that definition you can just take a code where the real minimal distance is actually attained and you also have a counterexample then.

Comment: Okay, many thanks. Can I ask if you have an answer for these two other questions?

Comment: I think I can answer both these questions but I have to admit that it has been a while since I did coding theory.

Comment: Oh I see. But I would really appreciate if you write an answer/comment, because it seems that coding theory is  kind of "unpopular" and hence I really doubt that I am gonna have any other response in my questions, unfortunately.

Comment: I added an answer to your question.

Comment: You are the best!